# Why the baked normal‘s color looks different when it's color space assigned as non-color?

Tags: normals, normal-map, color-management

[image]

Why the baked normal‘s color looks different when it's color space assigned as non-color, and it is identical in sRGB space. It seems like been appilied a 0.454? gamma curve onto it when the color space is non-color. I really know little about the normal science. And this might not be a big issue for the image can be saved in a normal look. If someone can give a quick answer I will be glad. Did I make a mistake in baking?